# Cant manage to attach a scrollbar to my div on overflow

Tags: html, css, dom

I've been trying to attach a scroll bar when my div with class "mytable" overflows.

It seemed to work out when I recreated a chunk of this html in a new file with fresh css but there's so much stuff to move that I'd rather figure out whats wrong with this one.

Below is the html structure I have and [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NFu41.jpg) is how it looks like on my browser

```
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
        <!-- The Modal -->
        <div class="modal">
            <!-- Modal content -->
            <div class="modal-content">
                <span class="close">&times;</span>
                <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="mytable">
            <div class="row header">
                <div class="cell small">
                    Kennel
                </div>
                <div class="cell small">
                    Type
                </div>
                <div class="cell medium">
                    Name
                </div>...and bunch more rows
```

giving overflow hidden property to the html and the body removes the regular scroll bar but I cant manage to attach a scroll bar to my main div which acts as a table with the class name "mytable"

Tried using fixed size on height or width as advised on similar posts but none of them seemed to work.

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 40px;
  max-width: 800px;
}

.mytable {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  margin: 0 0 40px 0;
  width: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to use `overflow: scroll;` rather than `overflow: auto;` on your `.mytable` ?

Comment: yep definitely did

Comment: Do you mind to share some more of your code so we can get a much better understanding of what are the issues at play?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your display property of .mytable from table to 'block' or whatever (except 'table' and 'inline' elements). It will start showing scrollbar

Comment: thanks that kinda worked out but not until I gave fixed height to mytable
which screwed up the scroll-bar when zoomed in or few more elements are added

Answer (score 0):

Try using

> **overflow: scroll;**

in the div you want to have scroll bar.

Comment: dude, it will not work for display table. and also affect same like 'auto' if element is overflowing